What is the smallest regular open set containing a given open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$?
Suppose $A \subsetneq \mathbb{R}^2$ is a bounded open set. We know it's regular if
$$
A=\operatorname{int}(\bar{A}) .
$$
Suppose $A$ is not regular.
By assumption, of course, $A=\operatorname{int}(A) .$
My question is, how can we "minimally regularify" $A$? What is the smallest regular open set containing $A$? If we call this set $A^*$, can we say that $A^*\setminus A$ has Lebesgue measure zero?

I don’t think it’s hard to show that $A^* = \mathrm{int}(\bar A)$. I’m not very sure about the measure of the difference though.

Note that $\text{int}(\bar{A})$ is regular, thus it must contain $A^*$. But if $B$ is a regular set containing $A$, then $\bar{A} \subset \bar{B}$, and so $\text{int}(\bar{A}) \subset \text{int}(\bar{B}) = B$. Thus $\text{int}(\bar{A}) \subset A^*$, so we can conclude that $\text{int}(\bar{A}) = A^*$.
However, $A^* \setminus A$ need not have measure zero, even if we're just looking at $\mathbb{R}$. Let $S$ be the complement of the Fat Cantor Set on the interval $[0,1]$. The key properties of the Fat Cantor Set are that it is closed, has empty interior, but also has positive measure (The wikipedia construction gives it measure $\frac{1}{2}$). This means that $S$ is open and bounded, has measure strictly less than $1$, but its closure is $[0,1]$, thus $S^* = (0,1)$ has measure $1$ and so $S^* \setminus S$ has strictly positive measure.
And we can extend this example to $\mathbb{R}^2$ by just taking $S \times [0,1]$.

Is it simple to see why the closure of $S$ is $[0,1]$?

@Pranay It follows directly from the fact that its complement has empty interior - since there are no open sets in its complement, the only closed set containing it must be the the full interval.

@LeeMosher Maybe "typical" is too strong a wording, I'll change it to read "the wikipedia construction". Obviously the exact construction and measure aren't important here.

Ah yes, I see it, thanks!
