Difference of a regulr open and another open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ must have non empty interior if it has positive Lebesgue measure?
$A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, open, bounded and convex with non empty interior.
$B \subsetneq A$, also open, s.t. $A \setminus B$ has positive Lebesgue measure. Must  $A \setminus B$ have a non empty interior?
My attempt: $A$ is, of course, a regular open set. But we don't know that $B$ is regular. Therefore I'm not able to easily conclude. If $B$ is regular, we can say that the statement is true, I think. Any help is most appreciated.

Just remove from $A$ a totally disconnected closed subset of positive measure.

Thank you for your comment. Can you pls elaborate? It's not clear to me. Thanks again.

What is a regular open set?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_open_set

In 50+ years as a mathematician — including teaching topology numerous times, this is the first time I have encountered that term.

Nonetheless, Ted, it's come up in another question just a little earlier: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4999903/what-is-the-smallest-regular-open-set-containing-a-given-open-set-in-mathbbr . And surprise, surprise...it's from the same person!

@Ted Shifrin: This notion played an important role in lattice-theoretic issues, and was much better known back in the lattice theory heydays (roughly mid 1930s to 1950s). By definition, regularly open sets are those sets that arise as the interiors of the closures of open sets. In fact, we don’t get anything new if closures of open sets is replaced with closures of arbitrary sets, and therefore regularly open sets can be characterized as the interiors of closed sets. Moreover, every open set can be made regularly open by the addition (i.e. union) of a nowhere dense set. (continued)

For these and other results about regularly open sets, see Abian (Chapter V.3), Birkhoff (Chapter IX.4), Engelking (pp. 37, 38, 57, 101, 122), Halmos (Section 4), Oxtoby  (pp. 20−21), Vaidyanathaswamy
(pp. 91, 94, 97, 99, 112, 115), Willard (pp. 29, 98, 164).

@DaveL.Renfro Thanks. Of course, one encounters this notion (for example, when proving the famous Kuratowski 14 set result), but I’m not enough of a point-set guru to have seen the term.

I assume that you know how to construct a thick Cantor subset of $\mathbb R$, i.e. a compact perfect totally disconnected subset $K\subset \mathbb R$ of positive Lebesgue measure. (If not, read here.) Thus, $K^2=K\times K \subset \mathbb R^2$ has positive 2-dimensional measure. Now, pick an open ball $A\subset \mathbb R^2$ containing $K^2$ and take $B:=A\setminus K^2$. This is your example.
